# How can I combine the readings of multiple lidars into 1 point cloud?

Tags: autonomous-vehicles, robots, signal-processing

I have a car with 8 lidars, each with a field of view of 60 degrees. My car looks like this:

[image: Car]

How can I merge all the lidar readings into 1 point cloud?

Comment: Hi Josh. I think you should clarify how this problem is related to AI.

Answer (score 0):

A high-level solution is to use the [NVIDIA DriveWorks SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/drive/drive-software).  NVIDIA's Developer Blog has a good post, "[Point Cloud Processing with NVIDIA DriveWorks SDK](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/point-cloud-processing-nvidia-driveworks-sdk/)".

*The NVIDIA DriveWorks SDK contains a collection of CUDA-based low level point cloud processing modules optimized for NVIDIA DRIVE AGX platforms. The DriveWorks Point Cloud Processing modules include common algorithms that any AV developer working with point cloud representations would need, such as accumulation and registration.*

I believe you don't need the AGX hardware for the problem you posted.